# sum of absolute difference constraint in optimization problem

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, constraints

I am writing a model for an optimization problem. I need to write the following constraint:

$$\sum^{N - 1}_i \lvert (a_i - a_{i+1}) \rvert \leq 2\, .$$

1. How to write this constraint (or linearize)?
2. Is it permissible to use absolute value constraints in an optimization problem (even for nonlinear programming)?

   After I searched, I found that absolute values can be modeled as the following (without the sum or difference):

   $$\lvert a_i \rvert \leq 2 \: \text{ to }\:  a_i \leq 2 \: \text{ and }\:  - a_i \leq 2 $$
3. Is this type of transformation is applicable here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to deal with this kind of constraint is to add "slack variables" to your system. In your case, let us say that you want to solve the problem
$$
  \min_a c^T a \\
  \text{subject to}\; \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} |a_i - a_{i+1}| \le 2
$$
then you could introduce slack variables $y_1,\ldots y_{N-1}$ so that
$$
  y_i \ge |a_i-a_{i+1}|
$$
and then solve this problem instead:
$$
  \min_a c^T a \\
  \text{subject to}\; \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i \le 2, \\
  \qquad \qquad \quad y_i \ge |a_i - a_{i+1}|
$$

Next, recognize that
$$
  y_i \ge |a_i-a_{i+1}|
$$
is equivalent to the two conditions
$$
  y_i \ge +(a_i-a_{i+1}) \\
  y_i \ge -(a_i-a_{i+1}) \\
$$
and consequently your initial problem is equivalent to the following, which is now an entirely linearly constrained linear optimization problem:
$$
  \min_a c^T a \\
  \text{subject to}\; \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} y_i \le 2, \\
  \qquad \qquad \quad y_i \ge +(a_i - a_{i+1}), \\
  \qquad \qquad \quad y_i \ge -(a_i - a_{i+1}).
$$